# My plot didn't show the result when the number of clusters is 2 in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, subplot

I want to show 7 different number of cluster in one picture, however it always start on clusters = 3
When I didn't use for loop to show 7 plot, it can show the pic when cluster = 2, I cannot figure out what mistake here

```
import numpy as np
import resources as re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset , h, c = re.load_csv("CIELab_dataset.csv")
Train_data, Test_data = re.train_test_split(dataset, 0.75)
#plt.show()
plt.figure()
order_plot = 1
for i in range (2,9):

  y_pred = KMeans(n_clusters= i , random_state=0).fit_predict(dataset)
  #Calinski-Harabasz- evaluation critera
  scores = metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(dataset, y_pred)
  plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], dataset[:, 2], c=y_pred)

  plt.subplot(4, 2, i-1)

  print("the number of predicted clusters",i,"scores:",scores)

plt.show()
```

[image]

you can see the first picture in plot is clusters = 3(3 different color clusters), and next = 4..at the end 8. but I think it should start on cluster = 2, but why it didn't show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the first subplot after you have already plotted the two-cluster data. 
You need to swap the lines with `plt.scatter` and `plt.subplot`

## Example:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = ['_', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'tomato', 'orange', 'darkslateblue', 'olive', 'orange', 'teal']
```

### Correct order:

```
for a in range(1,10):
    plt.subplot(3,3,a)
    plt.scatter(np.random.randint(0,10, 10), np.random.randint(0,10, 10), c=colors[a])
```

[image]

The top left plot is red, so, this is element 1 in the list.

### Incorrect order:

```
for a in range(1,10):
    plt.scatter(np.random.randint(0,10, 10), np.random.randint(0,10, 10), c=colors[a])
    plt.subplot(3,3,a)
```

[image]

Top left plot is green, which is *element 2*. The last subplot is empty.

Comment: Thanks again and totally understand.